# Location for Firefox .mozilla and .cache directories

Tags: firefox, caching

By default, when I run Firefox, it creates two directories, `~/.mozilla` and `~/.cache`. Is it possible to specify another directory for `.mozilla` and `.cache` directories? For example, `/tmp/.mozilla` and `/tmp/.cache`.

I've read [Command Line Options manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options), but I didn't find the solution...